# Что не так с данным алгоритмом (AES)?

Tags: c, алгоритм, криптография, aes

Задача: реализовать алгоритм шифрования AES.
Проблема: некорректные выходные данные.
Не судите строго качество данного кода).
Ключевые фрагменты моей реализации:

main:

```
//SIZE_OF_BLOCK = 4 
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ifstream in_f;
    ofstream of_f;
    char key[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};// ключ
    in_f.open("путь к входному файлу");
    of_f.open("путь к выходному файлу");
    in_f.seekg (0, in_f.end);
    int length = in_f.tellg();
    in_f.seekg (0, in_f.beg);
    char **arr = new char* [SIZE_OF_BLOCK];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_BLOCK; i++){
      arr[i] = new char[SIZE_OF_BLOCK];
    }
    split_the_file(arr, in_f, SIZE_OF_BLOCK, key, of_f);
    in_f.close();
    of_f.close();
    delete(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

функция шифрования:

```
void aes_main(char ** block, char * key){
  auto new_key = expand_key (key);
  AddRoundKey (new_key, block, 0);
  for (int round = 1; round < Nr; round++){
    SubBytes(block);
    ShiftRows(block);
    MixColomns(block);
    AddRoundKey (new_key, block, round);
  }
  SubBytes(block);
  ShiftRows(block);
  AddRoundKey (new_key, block, Nr);
  delete (new_key);
}
```

расширение ключа:

```
int* expand_key (char* key){
    int i = 0;
    int* out_key = new int [Nb * (Nr + 1)];
    while (i < Nk){
        int j = 3;
        while (j >= 0){
            out_key[i] += key[4 * i + j] << (3 - j)*8;
            j--;
        }
        i++;
    }

    while (i < Nb * (Nr + 1)){
        int temp = out_key[i - 1];
        if (i%Nk == 0){
            temp = SWord(RotWord(temp)) ^ Rcon (i / Nk);
        }
        else if ((Nk > 6) && (i % Nk == 4)) {
            temp = SWord(temp);
        }
        out_key[i] = out_key[i-Nk] ^ temp;
        i++;
    }
    return out_key;
}
```

AddRoundKey:

```
void AddRoundKey (int* key, char** block, int round){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        int temp = key[4*round + i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            block[j][i] ^= (256 << j) & temp;
        }
    }
}
```

другие нужные и не очень функции:

```
int RotWord (int in){
    int temp = in & BIG_NUMBER;
    in = in << 8;
    return in += (temp >> 3*8);
}

int Rcon(int in){
    int rc = int(pow(2, in - 1))%256;
    return rc << 3*8;
}
//Sbox, SWord - по сути одна и та же функция, только первая для 1 байта
//вторая для слова
unsigned char Sbox (char in){
    int i = in / 16;
    int j = in % 16;
    return sbox[i + j];
}

int SWord (int in){
    int rval = 0;
    for (int i  = 0; i < 4; i++){
        char temp = in & (255 << i);
        rval += Sbox(temp) << i*8;
    }
    return rval;
}
//SubBytes сразу для всех элементов байтовой матрицы
void SubBytes (char ** block){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            block[i][j] = Sbox(block[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
// циклический сдвиг всех строк, кроме первой на 1..3 позиций
void ShiftRows(char ** block){
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            char temp = block[i][j];
            for (int k = 1; k < 4; k++){
                block[i][k-1] = block[i][k];
            }
            block[i][3] = temp;
        }
    }
}

unsigned char mixcol [] = {0x2,0x3,0x1,0x1,
                           0x1,0x2,0x3,0x1,
                           0x1,0x1,0x2,0x3,
                           0x3,0x1,0x1,0x2};
//умножение каждого столбца матрицы данных на определенную матрицу mixcol
void MixColomns(char ** block){
    unsigned char mult = 0;
    unsigned char sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
                mult = mixcol[i*4 + k] * block[k][j];
                sum += mult;
            }
            block[j][i] = sum;
        }
    }
}
```

расшифровка:

```
void Inv_aes_main(char ** block, char * key){
    auto new_key = expand_key (key);
    AddRoundKey (new_key, block, 0);
  for (int round = Nr - 1; round > 0; round--){
    InvSubBytes(block);
    InvShiftRows(block);
    InvMixColomns(block);
    AddRoundKey (new_key, block, round);
  }
    InvSubBytes(block);
    InvShiftRows(block);
    AddRoundKey (new_key, block, Nr);
  delete (new_key);
}
```

обратные операции писать не буду, ведь они аналогичны вышеописанным.
З.Ы. Меня очень смущает алгоритм дешифровки в Inv_aes_main. Такой ли порядок следования функций при дешифровке?

Comment: Возьмите готовую реализацию и сравнивайте в дебаге пошагово. Вместо вас это делать никто не будет :)

Comment: Тогда подскажите функцию готовой реализации на С\С++ данного алгоритма. Я знаю такую для джавы, но для сей не видел.

Comment: Стандарт криптографии на C/C++ это openssl. Можете посмотреть как там. Только там будет все очень оптимизировано.

Comment: Советую взять сам стандарт AES — там в приложение есть готовый пример данных со значениями промежуточных шагов...

Comment: Буду рад, если вы подарите мне ссыль на стандарт. Можно ли увидеть их код?

Comment: https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.197.pdf